# Small caps acronyms with classic thesis

Tags: acronyms, small-caps, classicthesis

In an answer to my [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65806/acronyms-in-section-names-with-classic-thesis) about acronyms in section names with classic thesis I have been suggested to typeset acronyms using `\spacedlowsmallcaps`:

> In `classicthesis` acronyms is typeset with space small caps, as *Bringhurst* recommends in his book. `classicthesis` has a command, `\spacedlowsmallcaps`, which do that. I tried to redefined the relevant command in `acronym` (see section 2.2 in the `acronym`'s manual), but it did not work. I suggest you ask a new question regarding that, because then one of the gurus for certain will come up with a solution. – Sveinung

I, too, tried redefining the command with

```
\renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}
```

But I got this error:

```
...
! Undefined control sequence.
\hyper@@link ->\let \Hy@reserved@a
                                   \relax \@ifnextchar [{\hyper@link@ }{\hyp...
l.29 ...solutions are constructed using \ac{GRASP}
```

Note that if I redefine it like

```
\renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
```

it shows no errors, but the text is unchanged.

I also tried to manually use `\spacedlowsmallcaps` when declaring the acronym

```
\spacedlowsmallcaps{\acs{GRASP}}
```

but then Latex could not find its definition (also that would not work with `\ac{}`, I think the proper way is to use `\acsfont`).

I found this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8015/can-small-caps-be-automated-for-abbreviations-and-acronyms) (not related to classic thesis) where another command is suggested:

```
\renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}
```

but it shows the same error as the `\spacedlowsmallcaps` one. However I thought to write acronyms directly in lowercase and that works:

```
% \ac{GRASP}
\ac{grasp}

...

\begin{acronym}
  % \acro{GRASP}{Greedy Randomized Adaptive Search Procedure}
  \acro{grasp}{Greedy Randomized Adaptive Search Procedure}
\end{acronym}
```

However it is not very convenient during writing (I will probably stick with default uppercase and run a regex substitution on the final document), is there a way to fix this using uppercase acronyms?

Here a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[overload]{textcase}

\usepackage{acronym}

\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

% This does not work
%\renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}

% This works with lowercase acronyms (as 'grasp') but not with uppercase
% ones (as 'GRASPU').
\renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\begin{document}

Initial solutions are constructed using \ac{grasp}. \ac{grasp} generation is very fast.

Initial solutions are constructed using \ac{GRASPU}. \ac{GRASPU} generation is very fast.

\section*{Acronyms}

\begin{acronym}
  \acro{grasp}{Greedy Randomized Adaptive Search Procedure}
  \acro{GRASPU}{Greedy Randomized Adaptive Search Procedure Uppercase}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think we are going to need a full Minimal Working Example here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is only a partial solution, but it might meet your needs.  The problem is that `\acsfont` gets passed an argument that has lots of stuff including hypertext linking commands etc.  Applying case-changing commands to these extra bits causes problems.  My partial solution is to change the case of the text *before* passing the text to `\ac`.  You could do this as follows:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

% This gives letterspaced smallcaps but does not convert case
\renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{\textls[80]{\textsc{#1}}}

\newcommand*{\myac}[1]{{%   % Note: two sets of braces to keep \tmp local
  \lowercase{\def\tmp{#1}}  % Defines \tmp to be a lowercase version of #1
  \ac{\tmp}}}               % Call original \ac

\begin{document}
Initial solutions are constructed using \myac{grasp}. \myac{GRASP}
generation is very fast.

\section*{Acronyms}

\begin{acronym}
  % You could also wrap \acro similarly so you could use \myacro{GRASP}
  \acro{grasp}{Greedy Randomized Adaptive Search Procedure}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample typeset with acronym package.]

A couple of comments:

1. You must wrap all of the commands you want to use.  This can get a bit
   tedious.  (I did not wrap `\acro` above for example.
2. Be careful in defining the new commands to prevent extra whitespace.
   If you spaced out the `\myac` definition, you will need
   end-of-line comments to prevent this:

   ```
   \newcommand*{\myac}[1]{%
     {%
       \lowercase{\def\tmp{#1}}
       \ac{\tmp}%
     }%
   }
   ```
3. You might like to try the `glossaries` package which provides
   builtin smallcaps support and some nice features like `\Gls` that
   capitalize the first letter.  It is much more comprehensive, but also
   more difficult to learn.  Here is a minimal example.  Note: I cannot
   get both letter-spacing and first-letter capitalization with `\Gls`
   and friends working, but you might find it useful:

   ```
   \documentclass{scrreprt}

   \usepackage[smallcaps, acronym]{glossaries}
   \makeglossaries

   \usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

   \newacronym{GRASP}{grasp}{Greedy Randomized Adaptive Search Procedure}

   % This gives letterspaced smallcaps but breaks capitalization \Gls{}
   \renewcommand*{\acronymfont}[1]{\textls[80]{\textsc{#1}}}

   \begin{document}
   Initial solutions are constructed using \gls{GRASP}. \Gls{GRASP}
   generation is very fast.

   \setglossarysection{section} % So you get a section.
   \printglossaries

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image: Sample typeset with the glossaries package but no letterspacing]

   This uses the nice `\Gls{}` feature to capitalize the first letter at
   the start of the second sentence, but does not letter-space the acronyms
   in the text. The acronym in the list of acronyms is letter-spaced because
   the acronyms are inserted into a description environment to which
   `classicthesis` applies letter-spacing.

   Here is the same example with the letter-spacing version of
   `\acronymfont` uncommented:

   [image: Sample typeset with the glossaries package with letterspacing]

   Notice that this breaks `\Gls{}` because the first-letter is now wrapped
   in the letter-spacing machinery.  I am not yet sure how to fix this.